# Changing location of circles in a question using Qualtrics

Tags: html, css, qualtrics

I'm trying to make a question in Qualtrics in which 20 circles (with text inside) are positioned at 20 different locations. It should look something like the attached image when it's done.[Correct outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGR1W.png) However, the outcome is that the circles are in one column. [Wrong outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdih1.png)

Here is the code I used to create the circles and how I attempted to alter their position. The position of the circles do not change regardless of the code.

```css
.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
}

.circle1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  top: 100px;
  left: 180px;
}

.circle2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
}

.circle3 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  top: 150px;
  left: 100px;
}

.circle4 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  top: 200px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle1">Circle 1</div>
<div class="circle2">Circle 2</div>
<div class="circle3">Circle 3</div>
<div class="circle4">Circle 4</div>
<div class="circle">Circle 5</div>
<div class="circle">Circle 6</div>
<div class="circle">Circle 7</div>
<div class="circle">Circle 8</div>
<div class="circle">Circle 9</div>
<div class="circle">Circle 10</div>
```